# Redundancy in Motorola tag names

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen tags like `motorola-moto-g`. What's the point in redundantly prefixing `motorola-` there? Moto is just an abbreviation of Motorola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Moto" is part of the model name.  We tag devices using the `manufacturer-model` format and don't deviate in cases where it's easier to figure out the manufacturer.

Comment: Apparently even Motorola refers to the devices like "Motorola Moto X" in some cases. Never noticed that.